# Soft Question: Geometry of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds

So.. I was thinking about something last night and literally have no idea where to start.

Can the ring axioms be connected to topology? If so, how?

Basically, the motivation for my question has to do with the fact that manifolds can be classified in different ways. Likewise, rings (specifically, finite rings) can also be classified in different ways.

Is there a place in mathematics that connects the idea of manifolds from topology to rings from abstract algebra?

Comment: I don't know about rings, but topological groups are a thing...

Comment: You may want to look at scheme theory.

Comment: I'm wondering if, for example, the fact that a sphere cannot be transformed into a Taurus in topology has a correlation between how one set of equivalence relations differs from another (or however you'd define the difference between two rings).

I guess I don't really know how to phrase my question...

Comment: Aside from schemes, [topological rings are a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) and

Comment: This is a very vague question. Yes, it's true that manifolds and rings can be classified. But so can nearly any other mathematical object.

Comment: Well... I know what you mean Qiaochu. Basically, I am trying to figure out how to visualize rings... and see if there's a relationship between the idea of a "ring" and the geometry of a "taurus."

Comment: You seem to be being mislead by the ordinary meaning of the word "ring". There is no deep connection.

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha... thanks to Googling of scheme theory, I stumbled onto a good starting point:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_ringed_space

Ringed spaces is what I think I'm trying to understand.